# Извлечение данных из БД с помощью PDO и ООП PHP

Tags: mysql, ооп, pdo

Набрался сил и начал изучать ООП. Идет тяжело. Второй день бьюсь с проблемой. Без использования ООП все работает без проблем. За пять минут все было готово. Используя ООП пока возникают трудности. Две настольные книги не помогают, интернет тоже. stackoverflow.com помог решить другие проблемы с этим кодом. Где-то я упустил что-то видимо по незнанию или не вижу проблему. Собственно, есть класс ConnectDB с методами connect(), select(). Необходимо вывести простую выборку из БД. Для этого подойдет query().
Класс ConnectDB:

```
<?php
    class ConnectDB 
    {
        public $pdo;//protected $pdo;
        public $db_user='root';
        public $db_pass='';
        public $db_host='localhost';
        public $db_name='test';


        public function connect() 
        {
            try {
                $this->pdo=new PDO('mysql:$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name', $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
                echo "База подключена";
                return $this->pdo;

            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Невозможно установить соединение с базой данных";
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
        }


        public function select()
        {
            $sel = $this->pdo->query('SELECT id_user FROM users');    
            return $sel;  
        }
    }
?>
```

Код вывода данных:

```
<?php 
$test = new ConnectDB();
$test->connect();
echo $test->select();
?>
```

Проверяю var_dump($test->select()) - выводит bool(false)
В итоге данные из таблицы не выводятся. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: я не работал с Pdo, но вот такой формат `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);` написан тут - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Начните дебагать свой код. Начните понимать что происходит у вас в каждой строчке и правильно ли происходит.

Comment: public $pdo;//protected $pdo;
        public $db_user='root';
        public $db_pass='';
        public $db_host='localhost';
        public $db_name='test';

Эти поля должны быть в конструкторе

Comment: @becouse Без конструктора никак не получится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'mysql:$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name'
```

В одинарных кавычках не происходит подстановка переменных

Comment: Двойные кавычки не изменили положение(

Comment: Господи, да не хотите заморачиваться с правильным синтаксисом подстановок в двойных кавычках - ну так соберите строку конкатенацией! Суть же не в этом, а в том, что у Вас неправильная строка DSN получается! `$this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->db_host . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);`

Comment: @Igor Dyshlenko Спасибо за помощь! Понял свой косяк.